# How to run a function automatically in JavaScript based on screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm doing responsive web design. When I shrink the screen down to tablet mode and click some buttons, certain CSS properties are applied(things are moved around and others are hidden). Then when I enlarge the screen back to its desktop size. I want the properties to go back to the desktop version. How would I achieve that?

The current behavior is that the effect of the button remains when I go back to the desktop screen ratio.
The expected behavior is that when I go back to the desktop screen ratio, the CSS for desktop applies.

Comment: Please add a relevant code snippet

Comment: Take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can access certain properties such as [window.innerWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/innerWidth) which you can check to decide whether to run your function or not.

That's for JavaScript. If you want your CSS to be responsive to screen size, check [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), for example:

```css
@media (min-height: 680px) {
    .someClass {
        margin: 5px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS media queries.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) and (min-width: 300px) {
  /* CSS for screen width between 300 and 600px */
}
```

With JavaScript, you could listen for the resize event.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function(e){
    console.log(window.innerWidth);
});
```